# Computational complexity for HeapAlloc

Tags: c++, windows, heap-memory, complexity-theory

C++ implementation of `vector` relies on extending it twice when it's current capacity is exceeded. `push_back` operation, obviously, uses [`HeapAlloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366597%28VS.85%29.aspx) for this matter on Windows, and, according to C++ standard, should somehow [use amortized constant time](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/). How long does it take for Windows to `HeapAlloc`, and how could one compute that `push_back` uses [amortized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) constant time from this, without prior knowledge of the set of instructions in one specific program?

Comment: The assumption for `push_back` to be amortized constant time is that allocation is constant time. Whether it is in practise on Windows, I have no idea. Probably not quite.

Comment: It is covered well in [this question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9380/why-is-push-back-in-c-vectors-constant-amortized).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it is pretty safe to assume that HeapAlloc (or dynamic allocation in general, in any OS) is amortized constant.

First, when you ask the heap to deliver a given amount of memory, it has to find a good chunk of free memory that it can allocate to you. The internal logic of how that chunk of memory is found is specific to the implementation (but [there are some good clues to be found](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810466.aspx)), and could vary quite a bit depending on things like fragmentation and efficiency. However, if an implementation of a heap cannot deliver this in amortized constant time, then that implementation is really terrible. It is generally called a "heap" because the basic implementation for this "find a good chunk" mechanism is to use a kind of priority-queue or list of first-available chunks which can deliver the (near-)best chunk immediately. More sophisticated versions are not going to be worse than that on average (in amortized sense), but could involve additional "book-keeping" work depending on how it keeps track of free chunks and how much it tries to reduce fragmentation, for a starting-point, look at the classic [buddy allocator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation). So, that's for the "find a good chunk" part. There are, of course, many other interesting issues, like contention, but overall, it's still amortized constant-time (it's the constant factor that is much more important here).

The other part of what the heap does is facing the OS kernel (or other OS-related layers) to obtain additional memory whenever it runs out. Basically, the heap is a memory manager that obtains large chunks of memory from the OS (or back-end), and then micro-manages those large chunks of memory to allocate all the smaller chunks that are requested by the program (or front-end) (through `new`, `malloc`, `HeapAlloc`, etc.). Once in a while, you are going to ask the heap for more memory, and the heap will find that it has run out of memory to give, so, it has to turn to the OS and ask for another large chunk. As you see, the heap itself must now behave very much like `std::vector` in the sense that it has to exponentially grow in size in order to amortize the cost of the requests to the OS for more memory.

When the OS kernel delivers memory to the heap, then the cost is, again, constant (most likely), because it is probably implemented in a very similar way to the way that a heap allocates memory within the program. The difference is, of course, that if the OS runs out of memory, it can't turn to anyone for more memory, so it just fails instead. What is the most expensive about requesting memory from the OS kernel is the switch between user-mode / [kernel-mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_mode#Supervisor_mode), inter-process contention, and the expansion of the [virtual address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space).

> how could one compute that `push_back` uses amortized constant time from this, without prior knowledge of the set of instructions in one specific program?

Basically, the C++ standard requires `push_back` on `std::vector` to be achieved in amortized constant-time excluding the cost of the heap-allocation, as they specifically exclude the memory allocation time from the analysis, which they cannot really dictate or predict. But, you can test it empirically if you want, I have in the past, and I can say for sure (at least under Linux) that `push_back` on `std::vector` is indeed amortized constant-time.

Answer (score 1):

The term "amortized" constant time means "if you perform a long sequence of operations, each operation will take, on average, a constant time."  The way this works with a `vector` is with table doubling.  When your vector runs out of space, instead of creating more space for a single item, it doubles the size of the current vector.  This will take time equal to the size of the vector (*O(n)* for you algorithms people), but you only have to do it when you double the size of the table.  Therefore, if you start with a vector of size *n* and add *n* more items, the first item will take *O(n)* time (to double the size of the table and copy the old values over), but the next *n-1* items will take *O(1)* time.  This gives *O(n) + (n-1)O(1)* time for *n* insertions, or a total of *O(2n) = O(n)* time.  Averaging this gives out *O(1)* time for each operation.

Comment: I know the way it works with `vector`. The topic somehow describes that I am aware of what's written in a standard, doesn't it? The problem is that it's likely that you can not rely on the fact it takes `O(1)` time to run `new`.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the STL will use `new` (or custom allocators) so it is not required that `HeapAlloc` will be called on Windows platforms.

That being said, the STL documentation cannot guaranteed any run-time consistency with lower-level API calls, it just defines what is implemented within its own walls.

Also keep in mind that the implementation of `HeapAlloc` is subject to change between OS or even Service Pack releases, so any answers here can easily be obsoleted by future releases.

Personally, I would be more concerned about the number and length of locks within the heap (required to ensure data-structure consistency due to simultaneous access via multiple threads).

Further reading: [MSDN -- Heap: Pleasures and Pains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810466.aspx)

Comment: Sure, it's not required, but there's just no other way to implement heap, except allocating "enough" memory and building some C++ runtime specific heap under the hood. Also, I understand that `HeapAlloc` is subject to change, but there should exist some documentation for every specific Windows version. Problem is that `HeapAlloc` MSDN page doesn't contain such data.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph Lots of applications (especially games) use a custom heap implementation. Microsoft isn't in the habit of documenting/publishing all their internal algorithms, that's how they make their money. Even the [Windows Internals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901.aspx) books (which are awesome by the way) don't provide that level of detail.

Comment: Gamedevs usually don't go as far as to make a C++ compiler with the only purpose of writing their game. You're talking about the code with "placement new" implementation of heap, which has nothing in common with the subject. I said that compilers would have to use such tricks to implement usual "new", if they wouldn't use Windows-specific HeapAlloc. The point about MS seems legit.